# add style to strings

Tags: android, textview, android-styles

Can I add style to a textview in strings.xml file.I have a style as follows..

```
<style name="text_searching">
    <item name="android:text">dummy</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>

    <item name="android:background">@drawable/buttonbarbackground</item>
   <!--  <item name="android:textColor">#ff999999</item> -->
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
```

and I have assigned this style in strings.xml as follows..

```
<string name="text">@style/text_searching</string>
```

Is it correct...Please let me know if anyone knows..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is correct. Although its customary to place `style`s in a file called *styles*. All xml files within `values` are of the same `resources` type so the compiler doesn't care where you put each definition. The human, on the other hand, does...

To add this style to a `TextView` you would do:

```
<TextView style="@style/text_searching" .../>
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do with `<string ...>` there, but that is not a `TextView`, is a `string`.

**Update:** I *think* I figured out what you are actually trying to do, and it has nothing to do with `TextView`s. And no, you can't do that. You can to some extents use simple HTML tags to define text size, color, etc; then you would have to use `getText` instead of `getString` to get it to process the HTML tags.

But under no condition a `string` would have a background, that's just plain wrong.

Comment: Now I didnot get error but I am getting the Id of the style as @2134267

Comment: @indraja: What are you trying to do with that `string`?

Comment: I am trying to add that string in on createOptionsMenu as follows.. menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST, 0,@string/text).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

Comment: @indraja: Yeah, I figured your question about `TextView` had nothing to do with `TextView`s... Sorry, you can't customize a menu like that.

Answer (score 2):

Use a spannable string:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
SpannableString spString = new SpannableString("Background text");
spString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 5, spString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spString);
```

For details see e.g. [this tutorial](https://way2androidtutorials.blogspot.in/2017/08/spannablestring-is-class-its-extends.html).